# C# Call a thread multiple times but once at a time

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a kind of Web-Server in C#(for CGI). When I open the web page, it basically executes a method(that writes some text to a file). But the problem is if 2nd persons opened the page before the previous method ended, the server would call the method again and both would conflict. The web server calls the method as a thread. `Thread.Join` works for 2 threads.

Simplified - In my c# code, there is one method(thread) that can be called even when its one instance is already running and not completed. I need to wait till it exits and run again with new variables provided.

Code -

```
        private readonly object xyz = new object();
        public string module1(string txt, string phno)
        {
            lock (xyz)
            {
               ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                string crd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string udd = String.Format(@"--user-data-dir={0}\\Chrome Profile", crd);
                options.AddArgument(String.Format(udd));
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                driver.Url = String.Format("https://google.com");
                thread.sleep(5000);
                driver.Quit();
                return "ok";
            }
        }
```

This method can be run only once at a time or it will give error as Selenium only supports one chrome browser per user data directory. And since this method is called by API, it can be called multiple times. In reality, this method takes around 30 seconds.

Comment: you mean... you want to **[lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)** it? (that being said. if you want _any_ help that's more specific: _share. your. code._)

Comment: add code snippet so its better understandable

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Ok, the code is long. I will add minimal reproducable code in few minutes. Till then, yeah I want to LOCK it but execute it again once lock is over.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta that is _exactly_ what the `lock`-statement does. please read the article i linked ;)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Updated the code.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann if the lock is applied, the method does not run the second time.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta then something has gone _terribly_ wrong - can you please show _how_ you applied the lock? (also, now that i see your code and use case, i think a _queue_ would be a possible solution, as well)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Updated the code with lock. It is the first time me using lock. Maybe I applied it wrong way. I couldn't find anything about queuing in my case. Can you please explain how queuing might work?

Comment: don't forget, for `lock` to work, the statements need to have the _same instance_ of the lock-object. if you're using a class that's created anew for each request, they all have their _own_ instance of the lock-object, making it non-locking. (the quickest, dirtiest way would be using a static lock object)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Each request is coming from within the class. I am using NancyFX. It is sending the requests.